# Phone saves only the top left corner of the image - ActionScript3

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe

I am trying to save an image to my phone's camera Roll using Action Script 3. The image saves fine on tablet devices. However, when I save the image to my phone, it saves only the top-left corner of the image.

Here is my code,

```
var media:DisplayItem;

public function SaveAsBitmap():void
{
var cameraRoll:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
cameraRoll.addBitmapData(this.GetAsBitmapData());
}

public function GetAsBitmapData():BitmapData
{
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width,this.height, false, 0x000000);
this.media.DrawToBitmap(bmpData);     
return bmpData;       
}
```

How do I save an image which is larger than the display area of my phone? 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
  var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width,this.height, false, 0x000000);
```

Check the value of these variables: 'this.width' and 'this.height', probably it's not the right dimensions as you want.

To check the user screen resolution, you can try:

```
  // remember to import 
  import flash.system.Capabilities;

  trace('Capabilities.screenResolutionX: ', Capabilities.screenResolutionX);
  trace('Capabilities.screenResolutionY: ', Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
```

I also saw something on your code, I cannot see all scope, but try to do something:

```
  public function GetAsBitmapData():BitmapData
  {
     // you can replace this.width and this.height to Capabilities.screenResolutionX/Capabilities.screenResolutionY
     var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width,this.height, false, 0x000000);
     bmpData.draw(this.media); // be sure that this.media is IBitmapDrawable
     return bmpData;      
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @gPeart. I am connected to an Iphone5 and the width & height that I get back is 320 & 480. I am new to coding in Action Script and I am not quite sure how to find the stage size of the device connected.

Comment: You are welcome! 
I just edited my answer to help you how to find the device resolution.

Comment: Thank you very much @gPeart. I tried replacing this.width & this.height with Capabilities.screenResolutionX and Capabilities.screenResolutionY. But it still doesn't work as expected. Also, this.media is a displayItem and I am not able to convert it to IBitmapDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster stated, the problem is in the following line:

```
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width,this.height, false, 0x000000);
```

`this.width` and `this.height` are returning to you the 'size' of the device screen. What you need to put in in place of those items are the actual width and height of the image you want to load from the camera roll.